# How can I run as another user?

Tags: bash, debian, sudo, su

This is the bash code that should be runned. So first it substitutes the user to openproject and than runs all the code:

```
su openproject -c "bash -l" 
cd ~/openproject
git checkout Gemfile.lock
git pull

bundle install
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:seed
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I have tried chnaging the above script into this:

```
su - openproject -c "cd ~openproject/openproject"

su - openproject -c "git checkout stable"

su - openproject -c "git checkout Gemfile.lock"
su - openproject -c "git pull"

su - openproject -c "bundle install"

su - openproject -c "RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:migrate"
su - openproject -c "RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:seed"
su - openproject -c "RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```

but this does not run properly and at every steps asks for password. How can the translated script be improved so it works?

**UPDATE 1:**

After receiving sugestions about this I am the point where the code has been modified into:

```
cd ~openproject/openproject

sudo -u openproject git checkout stable

sudo -u openproject git checkout Gemfile.lock
sudo -u openproject git pull

# the output is good thill here
sudo -u openproject bundle install

sudo -u openproject RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:migrate
sudo -u openproject RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:seed
sudo -u openproject RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

The output is ok till the line that states so into the code. From there I get 4 error

> sudo: bundle: command not found

**UPDATE 2:**

After trying the suggestion from Dmitry Vasilyanov I found that if i insert the -i it will simulate as user login. However this is not the final way to do it.

If I run `echo $PATH` after logging in as openproject the ouput is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/openproject/.rvm/bin`

If I run `echo $PATH` after `su openproject -c "bash -l"` the output is `/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/home/openproject/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/openproject/.rvm/bin`

Comment: You want `sudo`, not `su`.

Comment: You also can't (meaningfully) sudo `cd`, since it's a shell builtin.

Comment: But sudo doesn't subsitute for root? I am root and want to run script as openproject user, with exact effects as if i would login as openproject user and start from second command (cd ~/openproject)

Comment: No, `sudo` is used to run as another user, being `root` the default if nothing is specified, you can perfectly execute `sudo -u openproject bundle install`.

Comment: I guess you are getting the `bundle: command not found` error because you set `PATH` or `GEM_PATH` in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, they are not executed in non-login/non-interactive shells, so you need to pass `-i` to `sudo` to simulate login, like this: `sudo -iu openproject bundle install`

Comment: @DmitryVasilyanov Thanks. Great suggestion

Comment: Well, now I guess you are getting different `$PATH` from `bash` and `sudo` because the `$PATH` is defined in your `.bashrc` rather than `.bash_profile`. The difference is: `.bashrc` is executed for *interactive* shells and `.bash_profile` is executed for *login* shells. When you run `sudo -i` your shell becomes *login* but not *interactive*, so `.bashrc` is not executed. Move the `$PATH` setting from `.bashrc` to `bash_profile` and then `sudo -i` will be able to see it.

Answer (score 19):

Why don't you create a shell script and do a

`su - openproject -c "your_shell_script"`

Be aware of the - before openproject. That will set the environment variables of openproject instead of your user environment variables.

Comment: I needed to add `sudo` at the start otherwise it asked me for my password.

Comment: `sudo` will also ask for the password the first time you run it, hence the advise of putting your stuff in a shell script and running that with either `su`or `sudo`

Answer (score 8):

If you use bash you can do here-doc

```
$ su - user -s/bin/bash -c <<EOF
export X=1
echo $X
EOF
```

That way you can execute many commands and keep the state inside a script.

The same with sudo

```
sudo -u user bash <<EOF
your
script
here
EOF
```

Comment: Neither works for me. Can you really pass commands from stdin to su/sudo?

Comment: @Sparhawk, thanks for checking. In the second example I forgot to add "bash" (already updated the example) – works. The first example is not fully working as you mentioned, I was typing from long term cache so I could make a mistake, but definitely I had su working with stdin (I was using java to run subprocess for that task) I'll try to test it more to find correct way.

Comment: I needed to create a command dependent on various variables and run it as another user. So the suggestion from YoMismo was not an option in my case. I battled this for an hour, an the only thing I find working is the EOF approach (the second example). Thanks!